# Get coordinate of marker and limit the values Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5

I'm using google maps on my laravel 5.4 project .

I need to to save coordinate ( lat and long) of markers on map, I can do it but when I save it to database it saves too long number like : (35.690833660667444, 51.39251243323088)

now I want to limit this number to 6 characters like this : (35.690833, 51.392512)

but I don't know how , please help me.
thanks for any help ;) .

Comment: Why do you want shorter number in the first place? Does your database not support this precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP's `round()` function to round your lat / long, you will, however, lose a bit of precision in this way. It's better to store the whole thing if you can.

```
$latitude = round($latitude, 6);
```

The `6` means 6 decimal places.

Comment: thanks for your help :)